# Execution reverted - transaction mined but execution failed

Tags: remix, metamask, etherscan, solidity-0.8.x, sepolia

I have looked at previous answers for this title but they don't seem to help me.
My [contract](https://sepolia.etherscan.io/address/0x55fB4183295E43B5B54935B03C996843Da23990F) contract is deployed and verified on the Sepolia test net using Remix.
This is the failed [transaction](https://sepolia.etherscan.io/tx/0xf97ae23bcf1a78138bbd0ca69e3fc3117441edf33abd905d4339aac245739d30)
The receiver [contract](https://sepolia.etherscan.io/address/0x235E90B9C5D25D0E889Da09a507f2942d6672B22).
My owner wallet, [0xb04d6a4949fa623629e0ED6bd4Ecb78A8C847693](https://sepolia.etherscan.io/address/0xb04d6a4949fa623629e0ED6bd4Ecb78A8C847693), contains: 0.611 SepoliaETH.
Sender contract code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Brave {
    // Balance variable to store received Ether
    uint256 private balance;
    address private owner;

    constructor() {
        owner = msg.sender;
        balance = 0;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(owner == msg.sender, "Only owner can perform this action");
        _;
    }

    function getBalance() public view onlyOwner returns (uint256) {
        return balance;
    }

    // Function to receive Ether
    receive() external payable {
        // Increment the balance with the received Ether amount
        balance += msg.value;
    }

    // Function to send Ether to a given address
    function sendEther(
        address payable _recipient,
        uint256 _amount
    ) public onlyOwner {
        require(balance >= _amount, "Insufficient balance");
        _recipient.transfer(_amount);
        balance -= _amount;
    }
}
```

Any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 2):

The reason is the usage of `transfer` instead of `call`.

In the brave contract you are using `_recipient.transfer(_amount);`

That means this call will only carry `2300` gas for the execution, which only works when there are no additional operations inside the same execution.

But in this case, the recipient is a contract and it contains a `receive` function, which updates the state variable.

```
receive() external payable {
    // Increment the balance with the received Ether amount
    balance += msg.value;
}
```

Which requires more gas than just `2300`.

So `transfer` wouldn't work in this case.

Whenever there is additional work to do along with sending ethers, you should use `call` instead of `transfer`.